# AEM6. XML import to JCR(Oak)

Tags: xml, aem, jcr, jackrabbit

During migration site from CQ5.4 to AEM6 I've faced problem in importing XML data to JCR.

On CQ5.4 we used "Content Loader Tool"(http(s)://[host]:[port]/crx/loader/index.jsp ) to load xml to jcr. 
Starting from CQ5.6.1 that tool was deprecated and gone. 
AEM6 doesn't have it also, the same like several  crx:Xml* primary node types(crx:XmlCharacterData, crx:XmlDocument, crx:XmlElement, crx:XmlNode).

I've tried to re-import data programmatically, below sample groovy script

```
importXML();
def importXML(){
    FileInputStream  inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:/data.xml "); // XML file
    session.importXML("/content/xmlNode", // Destination JCR node
        inputStream ,
        javax.jcr.ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_CREATE_NEW);
    session.save();
}
```

But as import result, I lost all sibling data. 
Imported data has only one node on each layer in JCR. 
The reason is Oak doesn't support Same Name Siblings (SNS).

http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/upgrade/introduction-to-oak.html 
http://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/differences.html#Same_name_siblings

I don't need support SNS or crx:Xml* node types. 
I'm happy to have unique generated names for siblings(i.e. node_1, node_2) and primary node type "nt:unstructured". 
Or any other jcr structure, that keeps all imported data from XML.

How to import XML data to AEM6? Help me out, please.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this will help someone

here is how I've done it using Importer:

1)here is a simple importer class

```
@Service(value = Importer.class)
@Component
@Property(name = "importer.scheme", value = "importedData", propertyPrivate =true)

public class DataImporter implements Importer {
private final String SOURCE_URL = "http://someserver/data.xml";
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DealerDataImporter.class);

@Override
public void importData(String s, String s2, Resource resource) throws ImportException {

    try {

        URL url = new URL(SOURCE_URL);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        Document doc = parseXML(connection.getInputStream());
        NodeList Nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("retailer");
        for (int i = 0; i < Nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) Nodes.item(i);
            String id = element.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent();
            String name = element.getElementsByTagName("display_name").item(0).getTextContent();
            String about = element.getElementsByTagName("about").item(0).getTextContent();
            writeToRepository(id, name, about, resource);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void writeToRepository(String id, String name, String about, Resource resource) {

    try {
        javax.jcr.Node parentNode = resource.adaptTo(javax.jcr.Node.class);

        //Say we want this to be a Page node (use NameConstants.NT_PAGE = cq:Page)
        //all of node types can be created this way
        javax.jcr.Node pageNode = JcrUtil.createPath(parentNode.getPath() + "/" + name, NameConstants.NT_PAGE, parentNode.getSession());
        //Page nodes need jcr:content node to hold all teh relevant properties (NameConstants.NN_CONTENT = "jcr:content")
        javax.jcr.Node contentNode = JcrUtil.createPath(pageNode.getPath() + "/" + NameConstants.NN_CONTENT, "cq:PageContent", parentNode.getSession());
        //set some properties
        contentNode.setProperty("about", about);
        contentNode.setProperty("id", id);
        //save session
        parentNode.getSession().save();

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
private Document parseXML(InputStream stream){...}
}
```

2)Then in CRXde under */etc/importers/polling* add new node of type *sling:Folder* and add some properties:

a) target [String] this is a path to a repository resource this resource will be parsed to your Importer Class.

b) source [String] this is if you're looking to import from multiple xml files
IMPORTANT the value needs to start importedData (as a property in the class that is where they link) followed by :SOME_VALIABLE this is a s2 varaible in the above example.

c) interval[Long] how often to run Importer

d) add an mixin jcr:mixinTypes type cq:PollConfig

This should be it and so far I was able to import any data using this techniques

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like the ability to automatically create unique nodes does not exist (JcrUtils for example has the [createUnique](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrUtil.html#createUniqueNode(javax.jcr.Node,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.jcr.Session)) method that will append numbers to conflicting node names). It would be possible to use XSLT to rename each node so that it is unique.